# Как найти две точки перпендикулярные отрезку на заданном расстоянии?

Tags: javascript, геометрия, three.js

Имеется две точки: `c`, `d`, через них проходит прямая. Имеется точки `AB` - отрезок. Вопрос: как выставить `c` и `d` таким образом, чтобы они были перпендикулярны отрезку `AB`?

P.S. Известны координаты только точек `AB`, а расстояние между `c` и `d` составляет `1`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое *"прямо-перпендикулярны"*? Чем это отличается от простого перпендикуляра? И зачем на рисунке всякое лишнее нарисовано, если вы только про `AB` `cd` спрашиваете?

Comment: выражение такое есть, но сути не меняет, они должны быть перпендикулярны

Comment: Окей, то есть проблема в чем - найти перпендикуляр к отрезку AB в точке A?  )

Comment: ну типа, но координаты точек cd, через которые проходит прямая - неизвестны, но имеется равноудалённая толщина от основной прямой - AB

Comment: По вашему новому вопросу - не дерзите, человек вам помочь хочет. Лучше внятно сформулируйте условие.

Comment: я всё понимаю, но зачем выставлять вопрос на стёб и кидать дизлайк на вопрос, если человек проявляет уважение ко мне, он то же получит и в ответ

Comment: Не было там стеба, не наговаривайте. А вот с вашей стороны уважение следует проявить в более точных формулировках вопросов и учёте комментариев (просмотрел их сейчас все для проформы).

Comment: окей, сейчас переформулирую, но смысл кидать диз, если можно просто указать в комментах на неточность, заместо радикального изменения статуса вопроса ._.

Comment: Минус мог прилететь от кого угодно, они специально обезличены. Не принимайте на свой счёт.

Comment: Откатил правку про Оси XZ, т.к. это не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Направляющий вектор

```
dx, dy = B.x-A.x, B.y - A.y
```

Длина

```
len = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
```

Нормализованный вектор (единичной длины)

```
udx = dx / len
udy = dy / len
```

Перпендикулярный единичный вектор

```
nx = - udy
ny =  udx
```

Точки (C, D) на перпендикуляре на расстоянии R

```
A.x + nx * R, A.y + ny * R 
A.x - nx * R, A.y - ny * R
```

Comment: @Kromster Ну я так написал, чтобы один раз вычислять

Comment: плюсую, сейчас осталось бахнуть его в функцию :)
пасиб ребятки, если будут вопросы, накину ещё коментиков/вопросов.

Comment: *"длина .. он считает длину! .. зачем? .. а! он будет на нее делить!"*

Answer (score 6):

Алгоритм:

0. Все расчеты удобнее вести от точки `A`, принимая её координаты за 0:0
1. Найти перпендикуляр к вектору `AB`
2. Нормализовать его (чтобы он был единичной длины)
3. Умножить на половину ширины - это ваше `c`
4. Умножить на минус половину ширины - это ваше `d`

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж речь про three.js и 2D, то:

```
var a = new THREE.Vector2(...);
var b = new THREE.Vector2(...);

var ab = new THREE.Vector2().subVectors(b, a); //базовый вектор

var c = new THREE.Vector2(-ab.y, ab.x).setLength(0.5); // перпендикуляр к (x, y) есть (-y, x)
var d = new THREE.Vector2().copy(c).negate(); // можно использовать d = c.clone().negate()

c.add(a);
d.add(a);
```

И если 2D на XY по каким-то причинам не мил, то можно это организовать на XZ в 3D:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 0);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());

let ptsBase = [new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, -2), new THREE.Vector3(4, 0, -4)];

let ptsNorm = ptsBase.map((p, idx, arr) => {
  let v = new THREE.Vector3();
  getNormAt(v, 0.5 * (idx % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1), arr);
  v.add(ptsBase[0]);
  return v;
});

let baseLine = new THREE.Line(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry()
    .setFromPoints(ptsBase)
    .setAttribute(
      "color",
      new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], 3)
    ),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: true })
);
let normLine = new THREE.Line(
  new THREE.BufferGeometry()
    .setFromPoints(ptsNorm)
    .setAttribute(
      "color",
      new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], 3)
    ),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: true })
);
scene.add(baseLine, normLine);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

function getNormAt(vector, distance, basePoints) {
  let v3 = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(basePoints[1], basePoints[0]);
  vector.set(v3.z, 0, -v3.x).setLength(distance); // вся магия тут
}
</script>
```

A - синий, B - аква, С - красный, D - желтый

Comment: там оси x и z, а не XY vector 2

Comment: @Leobuildru и в чем загвоздка? преобразование Z в Y есть -Z. И если вдруг захотелось таки работать с 3D, нахождение перпендикуляра  будет ровно таким же на XZ.

Comment: @Leobuildru Добавил сниппет в ответ.